# What object is Dr. Boyce holding in the briefing room?

Tags: star-trek, object-identification

In the scene from "The Cage" where the officers agree to use the ship's power to destroy the entrance to the Talosians' underground complex, Dr. Boyce can be seen holding an object that looks grey with a blue tip. It looks like a pen, kind of like a sharpie. Is this an error or is this meant to represent an actual in-universe item?

[image]

Comment: There's nothing in the script that explains it; http://www.knowitalljoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Star-Trek-the-Cage-Secretarial-Copy.pdf

Comment: It's worth noting that the captain also has a circa 1960s TV set in his quarters so this isn't the only anachronistic item on display. [Bellisario's maxim](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim) applies in full force here, that this show was made to a small budget, under extreme time pressure by people who were overworked.

Comment: Note, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyota_Uhura) entry for Uhura has her wielding a pen-like object as precedent.

Comment: It was probably a pen IRL, and likely a pen in-universe. I don't think they had a "paperless future" mindset when this was shot. IIRC, there is at least one device on the bridge which delivers a report on something by spewing a bit of paper... either this episode or the second pilot "Where No Man Has Gone Before".

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I think Uhura wielded a stylus, not a pen. Although they were probably not thinking "paperless" when the pilots were shot, their thinking had evolved only a bit later.

Comment: That's a point, at the time of the pilot it was all a bit more cardboard and sticky-tape than later. @AnthonyX

Comment: Well, if it's in the episode, then it must represent something in-universe.

Comment: I think it's a pen that represents a pen.

Comment: *Stella Artois* and *Sharpie* will still be in business 400y from now because both of those products are indispensable to janitors.

Comment: Looks like a Bic Cristal that was painted.

Comment: It's a Pilot pen. _Ba-da-boom! I'll show myself to the door_